# Sharepoint folder permission problem

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I added a folder on the documents section of my site collection and their is one person in paticular that is unable to get access to it. This person is in a group with someone that is able to access this folder. I have poked around to try and figure it out by am at wits in. Any suggestions on what this might be or what I might need to check?

Also, the folders where created by the system account if that makes a difference.

Comment: I've done some research and these people are having problems when accessing the sharepoint site on their laptop. They are using vpn. If they access it on their desktop via plugged into the network there isn't any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Check if maybe the person who CAN access the folder possibly has explicit permissions to it.